# Trace on nested objects couchdb update handler

Tags: javascript, couchdb

i need to edit nested objects with unique key's! in couhdb document, but i can't do it.
my doc structure:

```
{
 "_id":"20",
 "_rev":"rev",
 tasks": {
   "20.t01": {
       "name": "test",
       "status": [],
       "tasks": {
           "20.t01t01": {
               "status": [                   
               ],
               "name": "name",
               "tasks": {
                   "20.t01t01t01": {
                       "status": [],
                       "name": "name",
                       "tasks": {
                           "20.t01t01t01t01": {
                               "name": "name",
                               "status": [],
                               "tasks": {
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I nedd to push some objects into status array's.

The update handler function:

```
"status": function(doc, req) {
            var data = JSON.parse(req.body);
            var value = data.value;
            var path = data.path;
            var message = 'set ' + path + ' status ' + value;
            var pathar = path.split(".");
            var level;
            var body = doc;
            var evalstr = "body.";
            if (pathar[1].length > 2) {
                level = (pathar[1].length) / 3;
                for (var i = 1; i <= level - 1; i++) {
                    evalstr += "tasks[\"" + pathar[0] + "." + pathar[1].substring(0, i * 3) + "\"].";
                }
                evalstr += "tasks[\"" + pathar[0] + "." + pathar[1] + "\"].status.push(" + JSON.stringify(value) + ");";
            } else {
                level = 1;
                evalstr += "tasks[\"" + pathar[0] + "." + pathar[1] + "\"].status.push(" + JSON.stringify(value) + ");";
            }
            eval([evalstr]);
            doc = body;
            //doc.tasks["20.t01"].tasks["20.t01t01"].status.push(value);
            return [doc, JSON.stringify({
                reg: evalstr,
                doc: body
            })];
        }
```

how i write the design document update function for this structure in couchdb?
Tanks!

Comment: Could you post the part of code you have, please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For the partial update, you could look at the code I wrote for one of my library https://github.com/suhailgupta03/clack/blob/master/lib/CouchePipe.js#L200

Comment: The point is, that you will need to fetch the document, update the structure and then send a `PUT` request again.

Comment: hi. tanks you for answer. how i use that function?